# Setting up PXE using Windows Server & Tiny PXE Server

Tags: windows, pxe-boot, ipxe

I'm trying to setup a small PXE/bootable OS desktop for testing. I want to boot the OS over network. I'm using the built-in Windows Server iSCSI target and Tiny PXE Server. The PXE part seems to be working correctly. I get all the way to booting SAN and then Windows starts booting. I noticed once Windows starts booting, the iSCSI loses connection to the VM or the Desktop (I've tried both ways). I have the "keep-san=1" setting on which helps it stay connected during the PXE process, but does not help once Windows boots. Any suggestion on how to setup a PXE/network booting to a desktop PC or VM would be amazing. I've been Google-ing everywhere and I can't find anything useful that describes this problem.

Update/Summary: My goal is to network boot an image from my DHCP server. I currently have been trying Microsoft’s built-in iSCSI target, which uses VHDX files. I also am using Tiny PXE Server to give out the DHCPd proxy and assist with the TFTP execution of the PXE.ipxe file. The problem is that when I do a PXE boot Windows or Linux (I’ve tried both OS), they connect and then seconds later during the boot up process disconnect from the iSCSI. I tried other iSCSI targets with the same results. I don’t care what free product I can use, but I just wanted to PXE boot images so I can easily use different OS without HDD. So I guess you could call it diskless or network booting. Any suggestions would be helpful or if you need any more information, let me know.

Comment: iSCSI target boot is supported in Windows Server (only). What OS are you trying to boot?

Comment: I was trying to boot OS or Linux.  I got Linux CentOS finally working, but I was having issue with iscsi in windows losing connection during boot.  Had to use kernsafe to create a good reliable image and connection.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't easily boot Windows desktop OS-es using iSCSI, it's Windows Server only feature being officially supported within this scenario.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/iscsi/iscsi-boot-overview#BKMK_SOFT

*Applies to: Windows Server 2016*

There are numerous hacks being applied by mostly Internet cafes in Asia, but none of them is either reliable or Windows version independent, please see below.

2. The actual iSCSI target should work regardless of what, Microsoft insists on Windows built-in iSCSI target for no real reason. See, we tested LIO, StarWind, and even ancient IET back in the days to confirm them working just fine. It's iSCSI initiator which makes or breaks everything. Windows storage stack starts before network stack, so some very special dependencies were applied to Windows iSCSI initiator forcing it to support iSCSI boot. This is what people do for workarounds (network vs storage stacks start order, placing pagefile.sys on the virtual device et cetera).

https://github.com/ipxe/ipxe/discussions/324

3. ServerFault isn't really a place for the desktop OS related questions, it's SuperUser which has a focus on desktops. FYI.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28217/what-questions-belong-on-super-user-vs-server-fault

Answer (score 0):

keep-san = 1 has really no effect with modern iPXE. The connection should go away and then reconnect, since iPXE needs to disconnect and windows should takeover, but this requires change of network stack, and thus disconnection.

What you claim to be a problem, is by design with iSCSI and iBFT.

Once the OS has loaded its own network stack it should reconnect to iSCSI, if that fails you can investigate with for example wireshark why.